# How can I use multithreading / pfx in WCF Data Services to speed things up?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, wcf-data-services

Scenario : I've been working with a third party company who host WCF Data Services 3.0 some time ago and we only have API access to their webservices, and no, I can't speed up things by using store procedures because I don't have SQL direct access.

I've playing with PFX a bit and I might be so wrong by trying to use it along WCF Data Services. e.g

```
 public List<EntityA> GetAEntitiesBy(int customerID) {
            var result = new List<EntityA>();
            int lastResultCount = 50;
            int callsMade = 0;

            while (lastResultCount == 50)
            {
            var results = MyApiWrapper.CreateODataContext().EntityA.Expand("Customer").Expand("EntityB").AsParallel()
        .Where(c => c.EntityA.CustomerID == customerID)
        .Where(c => c.EntityB.IsProperty1True && c.EntityB.Property2TypeID == 1)
        .Select(c => c)
        .Skip(callsMade * 50)
        .Take(50));

results.ForAll(c => nodes.Add(c));

            callsMade++;
            lastResultCount = results.Count;

            }

        return nodes;
}
```

I understand that I'm only able to pull 50 rows max each time I do DataServiceQuery, my bottleneck is created after this function result go back to my webform, because later I do a `.ForEach` and for each row I get I need to run some other queries againts other services (WCF)

Any suggestions how to speedup this operation?

On the other hand, when I was debugging this method I found an error message "[Children could not Be evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456216/debugging-linq-children-could-not-be-evaluated)" when GetEnumerator is Invoked during the Parallel Query Execution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You certainly might get better overall throughput by issuing multiple queries in parallel.  Your client must be prepared for the possibility that the responses will arrive out-of-order.  The web service provider may place limits on the number of parallel queries you are allowed to make.  Be sure that you understand and respect those limits.  If the web service is already sub-optimal, depending on the size of their infrastructure, you may reach a point of diminishing returns if you issue too many requests close together.

Another option...

It looks like you're fetching quite a few entities related to a customer.  You might instead consider showing the first 50 when the web page is first rendered, and fetching the rest in batches of, say, 50 using Ajax queries.  The overall throughput would be a little slower than if you fetch them all on the server side first, then render the page.  However, the user experience may be far better (depending on exactly what is happening on the page).

Comment: Hi @Eric, Thanks for your response. I'm using ObjectCache for the output result, this data is showed in a Custom jQGrid (Pagination is allowing 10, 20, 50 and whatever number they want. this might be the problem but is whatever the user wants)

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data for multiple pages in parallel?

Comment: I'm fetching data for one single report (grid) in one single page.