# Linq to left join giving "Children could not be evaluated" error

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to write the following SQL query in linQ:

```
select b.Title, b.Author from CurrentRented c left join Book b on c.BookId=b.BookId 
where c.UserId=2
```

My linQ  is:

```
var BooksRented = from c in db.CurrentRenteds
                    join b in db.Books on c.BookId equals b.BookId into bk
                    from b in bk.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where c.UserId.Equals(UserID)
                    select new {
                        b.Title, b.Author, c.RentDate, c.ReturnDate};
```

However, when I am debugging in Visual Studio 2010, I am getting a "Children could not be evaluated" error.  Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: It is not an error. You can't debug linq queries from visual studio. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456216/debugging-linq-children-could-not-be-evaluated

Comment: Ok, I will use LinqPad.  But still my linQ is not good. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending my comment, this is not an error. You query looks fine but it must be failing because `DefaultIfEmpty` returns default value of type when no rows match, so you need to handle that:-

```
 from b in bk.DefaultIfEmpty()
 where c.UserId.Equals(UserID)
 select new {
               Title = b != null ? b.Title : "",
               Author = b!= null ? b.Author : "",
               RentDate = c.RentDate, 
               ReturnDate = c.ReturnDate
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a different alias in DefaultIfEmpty Look below.

```
var BooksRented = from c in db.CurrentRenteds
                    join b in db.Books on c.BookId equals b.BookId into bk
                    from d in bk.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where c.UserId.Equals(UserID)
                    select new {
                        d.Title, d.Author, c.RentDate, c.ReturnDate};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue when I have recursive calls in your DbSet entities like including properties that are not properly design.

In short, review your foreign key and primary key relationship in your database if you are using Entity Framework as your ORM. As some table are not working if you have bad Keys relationship.